# Need to restrict Data for certain profile

Tags: record-type, leads, sharing-rule

Is there any way to restrict data with a record type on Leads

Object: Lead
Record Type: Bank
Profile: Sales

I had created a sharing setting on Lead and added other record types excluding bank, but Sales users were still able to see the Bank data. any suggestions? thanks.

Lead - OWD Private

Sharing Rule - Criteria based

Lead Record Type = other record types excluding Bank

Share with Group - I had created one group with a user for testing, and used that group here

Lead Access - Read/write

logged in as that user and I was still able to see the Bank leads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Record types, by themselves, do not restrict data visibility, nor can you typically modify record-level visibility (visibility of individual records of a type, as opposed to the whole type or to fields on that type) based upon a Profile.

Instead, the native way to approach this issue uses the Role Hierarchy, Organization-Wide Defaults, and Sharing Rules. Your situation sounds like you need to have the Organization-Wide Default for Lead set to Private, and you can use one or more sharing rules to expose Leads appropriately to different parts of your role hierarchy such that your Sales team does not receive visibility on Bank-type Leads.

Units in the Trailhead [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/data_security/units/data_security_records) can provide assistance on setting up role hierarchy and sharing rules.

Comment: HI David, I have tried this, but Sales users can still see the Lead(Bank) Records.. I had updated my question, let me know thanks.

Comment: Record visibility is hard to debug remotely because there are so many reasons a record can be exposed. Start with View All permission, record ownership, and position in the role hierarchy.